# How do I download a mp3 file from my broswer in OSX?

Tags: macos, download, quicktime

After opening [this link](http://sound3.mp3pk.com/indianx/criminal/criminal1%28www.songs.pk%29.mp3), Quicktime automatically starts playing this song.

How can I make my browser download the song instead of playing it in Quicktime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the browser's terminology, but when you right click an mp3 link there will be an option such as **Save Link As...** or **Save Target As...** or **Save Linked File As...**. This option will allow you to save the file rather than having the browser attempt to play it with the default application.

Comment: Also, an ⌥-click works in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Also, it depends on what the browser is set to do with that particular type of file. For instance, see in Firefox, Tools > Options > Applications tab.

[image]

(Feel free to expand my answer here. I think some more could be said about browsers and MIME types - not that I really know much about it.)